# Use getBounds() Method for negative Rectangle width and height

Tags: java

I am making a JavaBomberman game for School,
I tried to make 4 Rectangles. Up,Down,Left,Right: for The Explosion

Up and left has negative Heights and Widths.
And I am not getting anything out of a `getBounds()` here.

the other 2 with positive `heights` and `widths` work fine.

Is this a bug that `getBounds()` cant take negative values?

Comment: Wait I actually ment, intersection of 2 Rectangles, 1 Rectangle has negative widths and heights.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)

> A Rectangle whose width or height is negative has neither location nor
>   dimension along those axes with negative dimensions. Such a Rectangle
>   is treated as non-existant along those axes. Such a Rectangle is also
>   empty with respect to containment calculations and methods which test
>   if it contains or intersects a point or rectangle will always return
>   false. Methods which combine such a Rectangle with a point or
>   rectangle will ignore the Rectangle entirely in generating the result.
>   If two Rectangle objects are combined and each has a negative
>   dimension, the result will have at least one negative dimension.

Is seems you can not have a `Rectangle` with negative `width` and `height`. Just shift you `x` and `y` and you will be good to go :)